# renderPlot producing error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently trying to use the renderplot() on a dataframe of values that are set by 4 sliderInputs and I keep running into the same error.

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic for random distribution application

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

sliderValues <- reactive ({
#compose data frame
  ws<- as.numeric  (c(0:input$sws))
  df<-data.frame(
      WindSpeed = as.numeric  (c(ws)
      ),
      CBH = as.numeric (c(input$sCBH)
                          ),
      FFMC = as.numeric (c(input$sFFMC)
                          ),
      DC = as.numeric  (c(input$sDC)
                         ),
      PCFI = as.numeric  (c((exp(-66.62+(-0.993*input$sCBH)+(0.568*ws)+(0.671*input$sFFMC)+(0.018*input$sDC)))/(1+(exp(-66.62+(-0.993*input$sCBH)+(0.568*ws)+(0.671*input$sFFMC)+(0.018*input$sDC)))))
                        )

      )



})

#Show the values using an HTML table
output$summary <- renderPlot ({
  plot(df$WindSpeed, df$PCFI)
})  
output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()

  })

})
```

I'm not sure why R is kicking out an error for this, but I'm new to the Shiny package and I assume it has something to do with defining my variables as I create them?  My end goal doesn't seem like it should be hard...but I've been stuck on making the code produce a graph for quite awhile.

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI
  (fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Wildfire Behaviour Model"),

    #Sidebar with sliders that demonstrate various available 
    #options
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          #Simple integer interval
          sliderInput ("sws", "10m Wind Speed (km/hr):",
                   min=0,
                   max=50,
                   value=15),
          sliderInput ("sCBH", "Crown Base Height (m):",
                   min=0,
                   max=25,
                   value=5),
          sliderInput ("sFFMC", "Fine Fuel Moisutre Code:",
                   min = 77,
                   max=98,
                   value = 88,
                   step=1.0),
          sliderInput("sDC", "Drought Code:",
                  min=0,
                  max= 1000,
                  value = 200)
          ),

        #Show a table summarizing the values entered
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("summary"),
            tableOutput("values")
            )
        )
    ))
```

I appreciate any help on the topic, and thanks for taking the time to read through my problem.  Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data frame (`df`) doesn't exist outside the `reactive` expression

```
sliderValues <- reactive ({
#compose data frame
  ws<- as.numeric  (c(0:input$sws))
  df<-data.frame(
      WindSpeed = as.numeric  (c(ws)
      ),
      CBH = as.numeric (c(input$sCBH)
                          ),
      FFMC = as.numeric (c(input$sFFMC)
                          ),
      DC = as.numeric  (c(input$sDC)
                         ),
      PCFI = as.numeric  (c((exp(-66.62+(-0.993*input$sCBH)+(0.568*ws)+(0.671*input$sFFMC)+(0.018*input$sDC)))/(1+(exp(-66.62+(-0.993*input$sCBH)+(0.568*ws)+(0.671*input$sFFMC)+(0.018*input$sDC)))))
                        )

      )
```

This block of code is actually setting `sliderValues` to be your data frame. But it is reactive so it will update when you change the inputs.

Within the reactive expression there is an 'understood' `return` statment that returns the last entry to `sliderValues()`

The change you need is how you access the `data.frame` inside your plot function

```
#Show the values using an HTML table
output$summary <- renderPlot ({
  plot(sliderValues()$WindSpeed, sliderValues()$PCFI)
})
```

As `sliderValues()` essentially **is** your data frame.

The way I prefer to construct my reactive data frames is more like

```
df_sliderValues <- reactive({

    ## code to generate my data frame
    df <- data.frame(a = c(...),
                     b = c(...))
    return(df)
})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(df_sliderValues()$a, df_sliderValues()$b).
})
```

Comment: oh my gosh @symbolix, you did it.  I assumed that it had something to do with the reactive function but I couldn't narrow it down.  I am so grateful for your help!  Now this won't be hanging over my head when I'm going to bed tonight.

Comment: @AlphaKevy no problem. I found the `reactive()` construct sligthly confusing at first as it's a step away from standard `R` functions. But when you get your head around it it makes complete sense in the `shiny` environment.